# Check the convergence of the series $ \sum\left (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{-n^{3/2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Check the convergence of the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{-n^{3/2}}$$

I checked this equation with the test for divergence but it came out 0. So, now I don't know the nature of the following equation. Root test and ratio test and limit test are not going to work (or maybe I am doing it wrong) and I don't know how to use comparison test in this question.

Besides, I am having problem with the power i.e $-n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ in the following question, how to remove it?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n})^{-n^{3/2}}?$$

Comment: Please check again your exponent 3/2.

Comment: @ProfessorVector yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{-\frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{-\sqrt{n}}=e^{-1}$$
where we used the known limit
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e.$$
Since the limit $e^{-1}$ is less than $1$, the series is convergent.

Comment: I had just one doubt, after using root test we can use another test to proceed as well?

Comment: @Iti Shree If the limit of $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ is less than $1$ then root-test criterion says that the series is convergent. You don't need another test.

Comment: I wasn't asking for this question but for some cases, if I stuck at a question.

Comment: @Iti Shree Sorry for that. So what is your question?

Answer (score 6):

To check the convergence of the series, one can forget the root test or equivalents or whatnots, and work directly with "hard" inequalities, since, for every $x$ in $[0,1]$, $$1+x\geqslant2^x\tag{$\ast$}$$ hence, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{-n\sqrt{n}}\leqslant\left(2^{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)^{-n\sqrt{n}}=2^{-n}$$ Thus, the series converges (and its sum is less than $1$).

---

To show $(\ast)$, note that the function $u:x\mapsto2^x$ is convex, that $y=1+x$ is the equation of the chord of the graph of $u$ between the points of affixes $x=0$ and $x=1$, and that $(\ast)$ simply states that the graph of $u$ is below its chord on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

The $n$th term is

$$\tag 1 \left (\frac{1}{(1+1/\sqrt n)^{\sqrt n}}\right)^n.$$

Now $(1+1/\sqrt n)^{\sqrt n} \to e >2,$ hence $(1)\le (1/2)^n$ for large $n.$ Thus the series converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

By limit comparison test

and using the fact that when  $n\to +\infty $,

$$-n^\frac 32\ln (1+\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}})=$$
$$-n^\frac 32(\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}}-\frac {1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n\sqrt {n}}-\frac {1}{4n^2}(1+\epsilon (n)) $$

thus
$$u_n\sim e^{-n+\frac {\sqrt {n}}{2}-\frac {1}{3}+\frac {1}{4\sqrt {n}}    }$$

the series converges.

Comment: https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html   according to this the result after limit comparison test will be $\infty$ which is violating the rule, then how did you proceed?

Comment: This is wrong, you should consider $$u_n=e^{-n^{\frac 32}\ln (1+\frac {1}{\sqrt {n}})},$$ instead.

Comment: @ProfessorVector is it good now. thnx.

Comment: You don't need the last line, it's clear that $\sum^\infty_{n=1}e^{-n}$ converges.

Comment: The equivalent of the logarithm does **not** imply the equivalent $u_n\sim e^{-n}$. Recall that $$u_n\sim v_n$$ means, if $v_n\ne0$ for every $n$, that $$\lim\frac{u_n}{v_n}=1$$

Comment: @Did if $u_n -v_n \to 0 $ then $e^{u_n}\sim e^{v_n} \iff u_n\sim v_n $

Comment: Sure, but you applied this to sequences $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ such that $u_n-v_n\to0$ does not hold.

Comment: @Did Where does $u_n-v_n $ go.

Comment: Tell me. (Sorry but where is this going? Your answer is wrong, simply correct it and let us move on, right? And if you cannot correct it because you are lost, why answer this in the first place? Beats me.)

Comment: For future notice, note that in your case $$u_n\sim e^{-n}$$ is wrong since one has $$\lim\frac{u_n}{e^{-n}}=+\infty$$

Comment: @Did Please, could you check the new equivalence. thanks.

Comment: And now we have an equivalent which 1. is correct, 2. has an unnecessary term, 3. is not necessary to solve the question.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima You only need to go to the term $o(1)$, i.e. stop after $1/3$ in the exponent (since $e^{o(1)} \to 1$). The extra $1/(4\sqrt{n})$ is not useful, and even (I'd say) misleading, since $u_n$ is also equivalent to, for instance, $e^{-n+\sqrt{n}/2-1/3+(\cos^{77} n)/(\log n)}$ for that matter. (I.e., unnecessary terms in equivalents are not bringing any information.)

Comment: But to avoid all that fun, note that writing $u_n = e^{-n+o(n)}$ is enough to conclude.